# Quasi-isomorphism of an $A_\infty$ module and its cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, higher-category-theory, derived-categories

Let $A$ be an $A_\infty$-algebra over a field $k$. It is a well-known fact that $H^\bullet (A)$ also has an $A_\infty$-structure, and further one can construct a quasi-isomorphism $H^\bullet (A) \to A$. See the notes by Bernhard Keller, [Introduction to $A_\infty$ Algebras and Modules](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910179).

A similar result is true if you consider instead modules over $A$, i.e., for each $A_\infty$-module $M$ over $A$, the graded space$H^\bullet M$ admits an $A_\infty$-module structure over $A$ and there exists a quasi-isomorphism $H^\bullet M \to M$.

I am looking for a "hands on" proof of the claimed fact about modules. Indeed the justification in Keller's notes is that every quasi-isomorphism is a homotopy equivalence, and so the derived category $\mathcal{D}_\infty A$ is equal to the homotopy category. I (for personal reasons) would like to know if a proof of the quasi-isomorphism could be given directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at the pertubation Lemma, it is usually formulated for $A_\infty$-categories, however, if you can model an $A_\infty$-category in that way, you should also be able to model modules, as those are just objects in an $A_\infty$-category themself.
Otherwise, if you are only intrested in the formulas: they are written down in "Fukaya categories and Lefschetz Theory" by P.Seidel page 17.
also, you can actually just do it by hand, since it actually suffices to give a quasiiso on the Endomorphisms(which control the $A_infty structure$) which are by definition the $A_\infty$-structure

Comment: I will take a look later. Thanks.